# Can't override Meteor absoluteUrl?

Tags: windows, meteor

I'm trying to override the absoluteUrl in combination with a deployment on a Windows server.

On the server in Meteor.startup I'm doing this:

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl({rootUrl: "http://example.com"});
```

Calling Meteor.absoluteUrl() in the console returns: `http://localhost:3000`.

Any suggestions are most welcome. Doing this Meteor.absoluteUrl({replaceLocalhost:true}); also doesn't have any effect at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl.defaultOptions.rootUrl = "http://mydomain.com"
```

In your Meteor.startup. If its not for individualizing settings you can also use the environmental variable `ROOT_URL`

Comment: Thanks, adding that on the client works! Its also possible to define it from the browser console! Also when insecure has been removed and site started with --production. Isn't that a security risk!

Comment: The rootUrl isn't persistent when the above is run so it only affects the client running it so I wouldn't consider it a security risk